# How can I determine why the stack reserve/commit size for an .exe/.dll is set to a non-default value?

Tags: c#, winapi, linker

I have a Visual Studio solution with 100+ projects, all of them C#. At the end of the build, some of them have the [stack reserve header field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations) set to non-default values (4MB stack reserve instead of 1MB), confirmed by running `dumpbin /headers`. This is undesirable.

As far as I can tell, there are no post-build steps modifying the image to insert the non-default stack reserve size. There are no invocations of [`EDITBIN /STACK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack), confirmed by static inspection and by running Process Monitor. I don't see any suspicious NuGet packages that may be modifying the output, either.

What else can I do to determine why the non-default value ends up in some of the .dll/.exe files produced by the build?

Comment: in linker command line no `/STACK:4194304` option ?

Comment: No. Also, these are all C# projects -- they do not have linker command line options.

Comment: i not familiar with c#, but think the pe file anyway build with *link.exe* and some options used here

Comment: You get 4MB when the project targets x64.  Not usually desirable, you'd favor AnyCPU.  Only the setting of the EXE project actually matters since that is the one for which the OS has to create the thread.  The one that calls Main().

Comment: @HansPassant The .exe project targets x64, but I have many projects in that solution. All of them target x64, and only some of them have a 4MB stack reserve in the PE. Most of them have 1MB. What gives?

Comment: I only know why you get a 4MB reserve, you haven't told me enough about the ones that don't.  A standard mistake is paying too much attention to the solution platform name.  It is irrelevant for managed projects, only the jitter overrides in the Project > Properties > Build tab matter.  Targeting x64 in a library project is not useful, only the EXE setting matters.

Comment: @SashaGoldshtein You might want to rule out the possibility that someone used the `Thread` class `ctor` that lets them set the *maxStackSize* to greater than the default 1 MB size. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Thanks, but I’m talking about the PE header which is set before the process even runs and affects all threads, not just managed threads created with the Thread constructor.

Comment: Shooting in the dark here: perhaps set msbuild verbosity to diagnostic and compare the outputs of two different-stack-sizes-but-otherwise-identical projects? Some exotic buil task might surface.

Comment: In my experiment when I target AnyCPU, then I get 1 Mb. When I target x64 explicitly for DLL, then I get 4 Mb. And CoreCLR ILAsm sources are quite straightforward here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/439ec81edbc96bb3dfa7475d72680fa81adceb71/src/dlls/mscorpe/pewriter.cpp#L844-L866